# Time Series model parameters questions

Tags: deep-learning, time-series, lstm

I've read many resources on the net regarding the paramters [samples, timesteps, features]. And, I want to clarify two things:

1. I saw some examples that I can't say why to pick them in one way or the other.
   For example, here
   https://machinelearningmastery.com/use-different-batch-sizes-training-predicting-python-keras/
   (great resources by the way), the author pick the two sequences to be 2 features

   ```
   1  0.1  0.0
   2  0.2  0.1
   3  0.3  0.2
   4  0.4  0.3
   5  0.5  0.4
   6  0.6  0.5
   7  0.7  0.6
   8  0.8  0.7
   9  0.9  0.8
   ```

However, I don't see why they are not two samples with 1 feature and 9 timesteps, is this the same?

2. Lets say that I have a dataframe with 50 rows of 9 columns (that will be features fet1,...,fet9).
   But, they are actually triplets of three days, so actually the sequence is something like
   `day1_fet1, day1_fet2, day1_fet3, day2_fet1,....,day3_fet3)`, and one target column (i.e., many to one situation). I tried to reshape such that the new rows are

   ```
   day1_fet1, day1_fet2, day1_fet3
   day2_fet1 etc....
   ```

So that timesteps=3 and features=3 (And I want any set of 3 rows 0-2, 3-5 etc.. will be a sample).

Is this sounds ok? And what will happen if I'll keep all 9 features in the same row, is it possible also? 
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Well, it all depends on what you expect to be the output of your model. Normally, only the features of each time stamp should be in that row.

I assume that in your example the second row start from 4th day data. So it makes more sense to have separate row for each timestamp. But you can also test the model when there are 3 days in each row. In this case each prediction step predicts 3 days data.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, any row is combined of 3 days (not the same days, but think of it as a different prediction), so there will be no day4, just again days 1-3 but of different scale (its aggregated data and this days represent some conditions of different prespective). In any case, the target (which is one value) should be a prediction of total income of the store, as a function of the store income on days 1-3, and some other features that are time related for there days (so now any row could represent different store or something like it).

Comment: Then keep them in one row. But the question is why using LSTM? Are those sequences (rows) representing the data over time or space? or just independent data? if the latter is the case you won't get any benefits of LSTM.

Comment: Ttrying to see if there is a connection between shops or not, I agree that if not then this model won't give any benefit.